# Outlook 2010 Not Responding through out day over WAN

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, wide-area-network

I have a group of users who get "Not Responding" in the title bar of Outlook 2011 for 30-90 seconds at various times throughout the day. I have used the Outlook Connectivity Tool from MS's website to verify that the remote PCs have not Connectivity issues, and found none. The Exchange/Windows Logs do not revel anything obvious to me. Looking at the Network, the Firewalls do not show that they are dropping any packets, the bandwidth seems to hover are 10-15%, except when the SAN is doing a remote snapshot, which pushes bandwidth to 40-45% for 5-10 minutes. I have Deleted the OSTs of these users, and even upgraded two users' PCs as part of our upgrade process, and the problem remains.  I cannot find any pattern in the size of the mailboxes (some are large, some are small), or when the delay happens.  The only thing the users have in common is that they are all in a remote office connected via a 10MB VPN.  However the majority of users at that site do not have the issue.

I'm out of things to check.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Environment:

- Exchange 2010 on Win2008R2 (VMware) as a Single Server with all roles
- Two DCs in each facility.
- WatchGuard XTM series Firewalls in both sites, each connected to a 10MB internet connection.
- Pings between the two facilities is consistently in the 65-75ms range and jitter is typically below 10ms

Would a CAS server at the remote site help?

Comment: A CAS server would not help; it would do very little at all, since the mailboxes are at a different AD site.

Comment: You haven't described any troubleshooting you've done at the network later (could there be congestion on the pipe? We don't know!), or at the CAS server using the logs.

Comment: I have used the Outlook Connectivity Tool from MS's website to verify that the remote PCs have not Connectivity issues, and found none.  The Exchange/Windows Logs do not revel anything obvious to me.  Looking at the Network,  the Firewalls do not show that they are dropping any packets, the bandwidth seems to hover are 10-15%, except when the SAN is doing a remote snapshot, which pushes bandwidth to 40-45% for 5-10 minutes.   Is there a specific troubleshooting you'd recommend to start with?

Comment: Those were what I wanted to see from you. That's useful information to put into the question - the things you've ruled out (and how you've done so.)